# Bibliography does not show up

Tags: bibliographies

The bibliography does not show up at the end of my document. But the file is detected and well read, since there is autofill when I write `cite{`. Here is a short version of my code:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Einstein}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The log is : *"This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 20.7) The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file main.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux (There were 3 error messages)"*

I know this a recurrent issue but the answers I have read do not seem to solve my problem...
Thanks for the help.

Comment: you should call biber not bibtex.

Comment: Conversely, if you *do* want to use bibtex rather than biber, you need to change `\usepackage{biblatex}` to `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`.

Comment: As Ulrike says, the document needs to be compiled with Biber, but the error message shows that BibTeX is being run. If you compile your document manually, just call `biber <filename>` instead of `bibtex <filename>`/`bibtex <filename>.aux`. If your editor runs BibTeX and friends for you, configure it to run Biber, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864